# About auto filling function with the perfect number

Tags: c#

I have to make a program that simulate singing tournament. I finished the question (almost) but I need a more of a realistic kind of function that fills 1000 to 20 people in an array.

I tried to make an infinite loop until that success but it takes a lot of time so I deleted it, and I tried to fill random with a (0, 1001-(the amount of votes until now )) but unfortunately most of the votes are going to the first two and then all would have zeroes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp0
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int[] A = new int[20];
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int jmo3 = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == A.Length - 1) 
                    A[i] = 1000 - jmo3; // so it can fill the last spot with the rest of the votes
                else
                {
                    A[i] = rnd.Next(0, 1001 - jmo3);
                    jmo3 += A[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need the numbers to be normal with the same chance of the 20th guy to win just like the 1st one :)

Comment: I am not sure to understand everything, tell me if I'm wrong. You have 20 singers (so an `int[20]`) and 1000 votes? You want these 1000 votes to be shared in the 20 singers? Something like (for 5 singers) { 197, 201, 194, 199, 209 }?

Comment: Yes what is the goal of your program? Who is the winner? What is the problem?

Comment: So, choose a random number between 0 and the max index of your `A` array (19 right now) and increment that array location (integer).  Repeat 1000 times.  You've now collected 1000 random votes yes?  If you mean until someone receives 1000 votes, do the selection until the array location you just incremented is equal to 1000.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean with " a realistic kind of function that fills 1000 to 20 people." What do you mean realistic (what make it unrealistic)? You have 1000 what and 20 what? "1000 to 20 people" is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

For the case where you want 1000 votes between all entries in `A`

```
int[] A = new int[20];
Random rnd = new Random();

// repeat for 1000 votes
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    // select a random singer (by his index)
    int index = rnd.Next(0, A.Length);
    // add one vote for this singer
    A[index]++;
}
```

For the case where you want to keep voting until one entry in `A` is 1000

```
int[] A = new int[20];
Random rnd = new Random();
int index;

// repeat
do
{
    // select a random singer (by his index)
    index = rnd.Next(0, A.Length);
    // add one vote for this singer
    A[index]++;
}
// until one singer has 1000 votes
while(A[index] < 1000)
```

Or did you mean something else completely different?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand a C# class that does not **start** with OOP principals.

This problem makes much more sense if a `Contest` class is defined that handles all the mechanics of voting and such.

There is an array named `Votes` that contains the total votes each participant has. To vote for someone, increment the value in the array. Do that 1000 times and you have 1000 votes distributed among the participants.

```
public class Contest
{
    static readonly Random rng = new Random();

    public Contest(int n_participants)
    {
        this.Votes = new int[n_participants];
    }
    public int Participants => Votes.Length;
    public int[] Votes { get; }
    public int TotalVotes => Votes.Sum();

    public void VoteFor(int index)
    {
        this.Votes[index] += 1;
    }

    public void VoteRandom()
    {
        int index = rng.Next(0, Votes.Length);
        VoteFor(index);
    }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Singing contest with 20 participants.
        var singing_contest = new Contest(20);
        // Gather 1000 random votes
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            singing_contest.VoteRandom();
        }

        // Tally up the votes
        for (int i = 0; i < singing_contest.Participants; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Participant# : {i+1}, Votes = {singing_contest.Votes[i]}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Total Votes = {singing_contest.TotalVotes}");

        Console.WriteLine("Press [Enter] to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

[image: scr]